# Opening CTF and DAT files in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, import, file-formats

How does one open CTF and DAT files as listed [here](http://www.cms.fu-berlin.de/sfb/sfb267/download/list_of_data/catalogue/central_andean/geology/frac_reuther.zip) using ArcGIS 10.3?

I looked for instructions on their [WELCOME to the Geoscientific Database Guide website](http://www.cms.fu-berlin.de/sfb/sfb267/results/data_catalogue/index.html) but there isn't much guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to their [website](http://www.cms.fu-berlin.de/sfb/sfb267/index.html):

> The Colaborative Research Center (SFB 267) "Deformation processes in
>   the Andes" was a long-term project which comprised about 30 task
>   groups which were investigating the crustal processes acting at this
>   convergent plate margin.

If you receive no answers here that help you to read the *.ctf and/or *.dat formats that their project used, and in any event, I recommend that you try to contact someone from that project to ask them direct.

Comment: thanks - i sent them a note. I thought someone here might have some knowledge on how to handle the files.